# Group operations on Montgomery Curves in affine representation

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to understand group operations on elliptic Montgomery curves in affine representation. Let's say the curve I use is Curve25519, i.e.:

$$y^2 = x^3 + A\,x^2 + x\quad\text{where}\quad A=486662 \quad\text{over the finite field}\quad \mathbb{F}_{2^{255}-19}$$

Now, let's take two points on this curve in affine representation:
$$\begin{align}
P &= ({\scriptstyle 9,\ 43114425171068552920764898935933967039370386198203806730763910166200978582548})\\
Q &= ({\scriptstyle 14847277145635483483963372537557091634710985132825781088887140890597596352251}, \\
& \qquad{\scriptstyle 48981431527428949880507557032295310859754924433568441600873610210018059225738})
\end{align}$$

Their sum, according to SAGE, should be
$$\begin{align}
P + Q &= (\scriptstyle 12697861248284385512127539163427099897745340918349830473877503196793995869202, \\ 
& \qquad{\scriptstyle 39113539887452079713994524130201898724087778094240617142109147539155741236674})\end{align}$$

Now I'm trying to calculate this $P + Q$ in affine space (projective coordinates lose the $y$ coordinate, which I happen to be interested in). Montgomery gives in his paper "Speeding the Pollard and Elliptic Curve Methods of Factorization" from 1987 the formula on page 19:

$$x_3 = \left(\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}\right)^2 - A - x_1 - x_2$$

This works great in SAGE:

```
x1 = F(9)
y1 = F(43114425171068552920764898935933967039370386198203806730763910166200978582548)
x2 = F(14847277145635483483963372537557091634710985132825781088887140890597596352251)
y2 = F(48981431527428949880507557032295310859754924433568441600873610210018059225738)

print(((y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)) ** 2 - F(486662) - x1 - x2)
```

Which gives me the correct $x$ coordinate of $P+Q$. But how do I get the $y$ coordinate of the point addition? The Montgomery paper does not mention it and all references that I've found so far only use projective coordinates (where $y$ is discarded).

A solution I thought of was to recover $y$ from the calcuated $x$ by doing a square root -- but this would be ambiguous (give me two possible solutions) and I don't know which one I should accept as the correct one. Also I'd like to avoid the performance penalty for the Tonelli-Shanks square rooting operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting $x=X-\frac{A}{3}$ should transform the Montgomery form to short Weierstrass form. Then you can use the known Weierstrass formulae.

However, to save work, helpful people have prepared an [explicit formulas database](http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/) which might interest you, particularly [this entry](http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom.html).
It should give you
$$y_3 = (2x_1+x_2+A)\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}-\left(\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\right)^3-y_1$$
Combined with the equation for the $x_3$ coordinate that you have given,
this can be simplified to
$$y_3 = (x_1-x_3)\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}-y_1$$
This makes use of the $x_3$ computed before.
The formula is plausible: You can easily interpret it as calculating
the $y$ coordinate corresponding to the line through $P$ and $Q$ at $x=x_3$
and then flipping its sign.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly it! :-)